# How to auto-check the checkbox when data is enteres in that specific row

Tags: angular, checkbox, angular-material, toggle

I am using angular mastertoggle for table with selection.
The table row gets selected when the checkbox of that row is clicked
This table also has an input field

How can I auto select that row when the user fills the field. I want the checkbox to be checked both when clicked or when the user fills a field in that row
[image]

this is the code for the main select checkbox and the checkbox of eachrow

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="select">
<th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
  <mat-checkbox (change)="$event ? masterToggle() : null"
                [checked]="selection.hasValue() && isAllSelected()"
                [indeterminate]="selection.hasValue() && !isAllSelected()">
  </mat-checkbox>
</th>
<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
  <mat-checkbox (click)="$event.stopPropagation()"
                (change)="$event ? selection.toggle(row) : null"

                [checked]="selection.isSelected(row)">
  </mat-checkbox>
</td>
```

the input field is a date

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="date" >
<th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> {{date}}</th>
<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
  <span >{{row.date}}</span>
  <mat-form-field >
    <div class="date-picker-container" >
      <input class="date-picker form-control" ngx-mydatepicker
             matInput [name]="date"
             [ngModel]="row.date|localDateToDatePickerDate"             
             (dateChanged)="onDateUpdate($event, row)"
             [options]="datePickerOptions" #datePicker="ngx-mydatepicker"

             [appRequiredIf]="selection.isSelected(row)"/>
      <button type="button" mat-button class="button-calendar"
              (click)="dueDatePicker.toggleCalendar()"
              </button>
    </div>
  </mat-form-field>
</td>
```

i tried modifying

```
[checked]="selection.isSelected(row)"
```

to

```
[checked]="selection.isSelected(row) || !!row.date">
```

it does check when a date is entered but this background colour change of a selected row or the intermediate check for the main select is not reflected

Comment: Share the input field markup.

Answer (score 0):

For your use case to work with template driven forms, the change detection would have to run multiple times. It does not. You will either have to call the checkbox's on change manually on data change, or you will have to use reactive forms (highly encouraged).